# Most efficient way to solve initial value problem with $(y')^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

$y'' + 2x(y')^2 = 0$

$y(0) = 1$

$y'(0) = 4$

I tried the laplace transformation and other methods without success,
because this is the first time I deal with $(y')^2$. Just would like to know which method or  trick should I use to deal with the  $(y')^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let y' = t.Now, we have,$t' + 2xt^2 = 0$

$\Longrightarrow \frac{-t'}{t^2} = 2x$

$\Longrightarrow\frac{1}{t} = x^2 + C$

We know that,t(0) = 4,
so,

C = $\frac{1}{4}$

Put t = y',

$y' = \frac{4}{4x^2+1}$

Integrate both sides and get the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just curious is it possible to solve this problem using Euler's equation as well?

Comment: @JKM Euler Equation which one ?

Comment: @Isham i think the op means this http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/EulerEquations.aspx

Comment: @Fred Oh thanks but  it wont work op's equation is not Euler's equation  maybe he s confused with $x^2y''+y=0$